# default export eslint issues

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Hi I have this code snippet that will update the isLoggedIn and user state of the application that i am building but i encountered this error on es lint. can anyone help me with this?

```
import { SET_MESSAGE, CLEAR_MESSAGE } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case SET_MESSAGE:
  return { message: payload };

case CLEAR_MESSAGE:
  return { message: "" };

default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

this is the error msg that im getting:

[Unexpected default export of anonymous function eslint(import/no-anonymous-default-export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyzrr.png)

Comment: What is unclear from the message? Did you read https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md? Do you think you _don't_ default export an anonymous function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function giving a name and then export it

```
export default function thisIsMyFunction (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case SET_MESSAGE:
         return { message: payload };

    case CLEAR_MESSAGE:
         return { message: "" };

    default:
         return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting this error because of anonymous function

```js
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
   //..
}
```

Provide a function name

```js
export default function AnyName(state = initialState, action) {
  //..
}
```